# Initializing a class object with the contents of a vector

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

I'm currently working on a matrix class and there is one part I've been stuck on.

If I wanted to initialize a class object with the contents of a vector for example

Matrix M = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Would I have to overload operator= or is it possible to create a constructor that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "vector" you mean `std::vector`, then you can obviously create a constructor:

```
Matrix(const std::vector<int>&);
```

---

If you meant the `{1, 2, 3, 4}` syntax, then you can create a constructor taking [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

```
Matrix(const std::initializer_list<int>&);
```